# Rounding a Duration to the nearest second based on desired precision

Tags: dart

I recently started working with Dart, and was trying to format a countdown clock with numbers in a per-second precision.

When counting down time, there's often a precise-yet-imperfect way of representing the time - so if I started a Duration at 2 minutes, and asked to show the current time after one second has elapsed, it is almost guaranteed that the precision of the timer will report at 1:58:999999 (example), and if use [`Duration.inSeconds()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/Duration/inSeconds.html) to emit the value, it will be 118 (seconds) which is due to how the `~/` operator works, since it's rounding down to integers based on the Duration's microseconds.

If I render the value as a clock, I'll see the clock go from "2:00" to "1:58" after one second, and will end up displaying "0:00" twice, until the countdown is truly at 0:00:00.

As a human, this appears like the clock is skipping, so I figured since the delta is so small, I should round *up* to the nearest second, and that would be accurate enough for a countdown timer, and handle the slight imprecision measured in micro/milli-seconds to better serve the viewer.

I came up with this `secondRounder` approach:

```dart
Duration secondRounder(Duration duration) {
  int roundedDuration;

  if (duration.inMilliseconds > (duration.inSeconds * 1000)) {
    roundedDuration = duration.inSeconds + 1;
  } else {
    roundedDuration = duration.inSeconds;
  }

  return new Duration(seconds: roundedDuration);
}
```

This can also be run in this DartPad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/2a08161c5f889e018938316237c0e810

As I'm yet unfamiliar with all of the methods, I've read through a lot of the docs, and this is the best I've come up with so far. I think I was looking for a method that might looks like:

```
roundedDuration = duration.ceil(nearest: millisecond)
```

Is there a better way to go about solving this that I haven't figured out yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "add" your own method to `Duration` as an extension method:

```dart
extension RoundDurationExtension on Duration {
  /// Rounds the time of this duration up to the nearest multiple of [to].
  Duration ceil(Duration to) {
    int us = this.inMicroseconds;
    int toUs = to.inMicroseconds.abs(); // Ignore if [to] is negative.
    int mod = us % toUs;
    if (mod != 0) {
      return Duration(microseconds: us - mod + toUs);
    }
    return this;
  }
}
```

That should allow you to write `myDuration = myDuration.ceil(Duration(seconds: 1));` and round the `myDuration` up to the nearest second.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it will do exactly the thing I was looking for. I also read up on the `extension` article that I guess you wrote? I had to update the version of dart I was using to at least 2.6.0 to get the extension functionality.

Comment: I'm curious to understand what would happen if the dart language implements a `Duration.ceil()` method in the future, would there be a collision? Does my extension take preference?

Comment: If the platform libraries adds a `Duration.ceil` method to the `Duration` interface, there will be a "collision" and the new method that will take precedence over the extension method. In general, interface methods wins over extension methods.
Adding members to existing interfaces is a breaking change already, so that probably won't happen. If the platform libraries decide to add an *extension* method `Duration.ceil`, then your extension will win because between extension methods, non-platform extensions win over SDK extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution according to the documentation is to use `.toStringAsFixed()` function

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html

Examples from the Documentation

```dart
1.toStringAsFixed(3);  // 1.000
(4321.12345678).toStringAsFixed(3);  // 4321.123
(4321.12345678).toStringAsFixed(5);  // 4321.12346
123456789012345678901.toStringAsFixed(3);  // 123456789012345683968.000
1000000000000000000000.toStringAsFixed(3); // 1e+21
5.25.toStringAsFixed(0); // 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea - but the Duration class doesn't implement this, as it's not a `num` - and I'm not sure which Duration method will emit a double - they all seem to emit either a `String` or `int`.

Comment: Then convert it to a number first.

Comment: The number in the duration class is also not a *double*, it's an integer (in milli- or micro-seconds depending on platform).

Answer (score 0):

Another more flexible option can be...

You can use this function to roundup the time.

```
DateTime alignDateTime(DateTime dt, Duration alignment,
    [bool roundUp = false]) {
  assert(alignment >= Duration.zero);
  if (alignment == Duration.zero) return dt;
  final correction = Duration(
      days: 0,
      hours: alignment.inDays > 0
          ? dt.hour
          : alignment.inHours > 0
              ? dt.hour % alignment.inHours
              : 0,
      minutes: alignment.inHours > 0
          ? dt.minute
          : alignment.inMinutes > 0
              ? dt.minute % alignment.inMinutes
              : 0,
      seconds: alignment.inMinutes > 0
          ? dt.second
          : alignment.inSeconds > 0
              ? dt.second % alignment.inSeconds
              : 0,
      milliseconds: alignment.inSeconds > 0
          ? dt.millisecond
          : alignment.inMilliseconds > 0
              ? dt.millisecond % alignment.inMilliseconds
              : 0,
      microseconds: alignment.inMilliseconds > 0 ? dt.microsecond : 0);
  if (correction == Duration.zero) return dt;
  final corrected = dt.subtract(correction);
  final result = roundUp ? corrected.add(alignment) : corrected;
  return result;
}
```

and then use it the following way

```
void main() {
  DateTime dt = DateTime.now();
  var newDate = alignDateTime(dt,Duration(minutes:30));
  print(dt);  // prints 2022-01-07 15:35:56.288
  print(newDate); // prints 2022-01-07 15:30:00.000
}
```